# Filter multidimensional array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a multidimensional array of objects that I want to filter as explained below:

```
let participants =
[
   {
      "participant_id": 2,
      "name": "Bond James",
      "allschedules": [
         {
            "schedule_id": 1,
            "name": "James_Bond_SIL_January_22 (AM) - 07:00 - 15:00",
            "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts": 31,
            "start_date": "2022-01-01 07:00:00",
            "end_date": "2022-01-31 15:00:00",
            "shifts": [
               "2022-01-01 07:00:00",
               "2022-01-02 07:00:00",
               "2022-01-03 07:00:00",
               "2022-01-04 07:00:00"
            ]
         },
         {
            "schedule_id": 2,
            "name": "Bonds-1:2 Schedule",
            "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts": 5,
            "start_date": "2022-01-12 07:00:00",
            "end_date": "2022-01-16 11:00:00",
            "shifts": [
               "2022-01-12 07:00:00",
               "2022-01-13 07:00:00",
               "2022-01-14 07:00:00",
               "2022-01-15 07:00:00",
               "2022-01-16 07:00:00"
            ]
         },
         {
            "schedule_id": 9,
            "name": "test april",
            "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts": 4,
            "start_date": "2022-04-09 16:00:00",
            "end_date": "2022-04-12 20:00:00",
            "shifts": [
               "2022-04-09 16:00:00",
               "2022-04-10 16:00:00",
               "2022-04-11 16:00:00",
               "2022-04-12 16:00:00"
            ]
         },
         {
            "schedule_id": 10,
            "name": "CP - James Bond",
            "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts": 10,
            "start_date": "2022-04-11 07:00:00",
            "end_date": "2022-05-11 09:00:00",
            "shifts": [
               "2022-04-11 07:00:00",
               "2022-04-13 07:00:00",
               "2022-04-18 07:00:00",
               "2022-04-20 07:00:00",
               "2022-04-25 07:00:00",
               "2022-04-27 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-02 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-04 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-09 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-11 07:00:00"
            ]
         },
         {
            "schedule_id": 11,
            "name": "James_Miller_App_Test",
            "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts": 30,
            "start_date": "2022-04-21 07:00:00",
            "end_date": "2022-05-20 15:00:00",
            "shifts": [
               "2022-04-30 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-01 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-02 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-03 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-04 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-05 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-06 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-07 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-08 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-09 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-10 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-11 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-12 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-13 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-14 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-15 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-16 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-17 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-18 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-19 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-20 07:00:00"
            ]
         },
         {
            "schedule_id": 12,
            "name": "Grouped Schedule for April 2022",
            "schedule_type": "Shared/Grouped Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts": 3,
            "start_date": "2022-04-28 12:00:00",
            "end_date": "2022-04-30 18:00:00",
            "shifts": [
               "2022-04-28 12:00:00",
               "2022-04-29 12:00:00",
               "2022-04-30 12:00:00"
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "participant_id": 3,
      "name": "Barkley Charles",
      "allschedules": [
         {
            "schedule_id": 12,
            "name": "Grouped Schedule for April 2022",
            "schedule_type": "Shared/Grouped Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts": 3,
            "start_date": "2022-04-28 12:00:00",
            "end_date": "2022-04-30 18:00:00",
            "shifts": [
               "2022-04-28 12:00:00",
               "2022-04-29 12:00:00",
               "2022-04-30 12:00:00"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

From my array above, I have an object called: `allschedules` that has its own objects. The object of interest inside `allschedules` is: `shifts` which has an array of dates. The objective is to only return `participants` that fulfil the condition where the dates inside the `shifts` array is for the current month.

This is what I've done:

```
participants.filter((participant) => {
        return participant.allschedules.filter((schedule) => {
          schedule.shifts.find(
            (shift) => moment(shift).format("M") == moment().format("M")
          );
        });
      })
```

but this returns the exact same object from the defined `participants` variable. So nothing is filtered. What would be the correct way of approaching this?

```js
let participants =
[
   {
      "participant_id": 2,
      "name": "Bond James",
      "allschedules": [
         {
            "schedule_id": 1,
            "name": "James_Bond_SIL_January_22 (AM) - 07:00 - 15:00",
            "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts": 31,
            "start_date": "2022-01-01 07:00:00",
            "end_date": "2022-01-31 15:00:00",
            "shifts": [
               "2022-01-01 07:00:00",
               "2022-01-02 07:00:00",
               "2022-01-03 07:00:00",
               "2022-01-04 07:00:00"
            ]
         },
         {
            "schedule_id": 2,
            "name": "Bonds-1:2 Schedule",
            "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts": 5,
            "start_date": "2022-01-12 07:00:00",
            "end_date": "2022-01-16 11:00:00",
            "shifts": [
               "2022-01-12 07:00:00",
               "2022-01-13 07:00:00",
               "2022-01-14 07:00:00",
               "2022-01-15 07:00:00",
               "2022-01-16 07:00:00"
            ]
         },
         {
            "schedule_id": 9,
            "name": "test april",
            "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts": 4,
            "start_date": "2022-04-09 16:00:00",
            "end_date": "2022-04-12 20:00:00",
            "shifts": [
               "2022-04-09 16:00:00",
               "2022-04-10 16:00:00",
               "2022-04-11 16:00:00",
               "2022-04-12 16:00:00"
            ]
         },
         {
            "schedule_id": 10,
            "name": "CP - James Bond",
            "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts": 10,
            "start_date": "2022-04-11 07:00:00",
            "end_date": "2022-05-11 09:00:00",
            "shifts": [
               "2022-04-11 07:00:00",
               "2022-04-13 07:00:00",
               "2022-04-18 07:00:00",
               "2022-04-20 07:00:00",
               "2022-04-25 07:00:00",
               "2022-04-27 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-02 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-04 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-09 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-11 07:00:00"
            ]
         },
         {
            "schedule_id": 11,
            "name": "James_Miller_App_Test",
            "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts": 30,
            "start_date": "2022-04-21 07:00:00",
            "end_date": "2022-05-20 15:00:00",
            "shifts": [
               "2022-04-30 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-01 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-02 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-03 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-04 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-05 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-06 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-07 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-08 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-09 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-10 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-11 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-12 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-13 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-14 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-15 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-16 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-17 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-18 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-19 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-20 07:00:00"
            ]
         },
         {
            "schedule_id": 12,
            "name": "Grouped Schedule for April 2022",
            "schedule_type": "Shared/Grouped Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts": 3,
            "start_date": "2022-04-28 12:00:00",
            "end_date": "2022-04-30 18:00:00",
            "shifts": [
               "2022-04-28 12:00:00",
               "2022-04-29 12:00:00",
               "2022-04-30 12:00:00"
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "participant_id": 3,
      "name": "Barkley Charles",
      "allschedules": [
         {
            "schedule_id": 12,
            "name": "Grouped Schedule for April 2022",
            "schedule_type": "Shared/Grouped Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts": 3,
            "start_date": "2022-04-28 12:00:00",
            "end_date": "2022-04-30 18:00:00",
            "shifts": [
               "2022-04-28 12:00:00",
               "2022-04-29 12:00:00",
               "2022-04-30 12:00:00"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]

console.log(
      participants.filter((participant) => {
        return participant.allschedules.filter((schedule) => {
          schedule.shifts.find(
            (shift) => moment(shift).format("M") == moment().format("M")
          );
        });
      })
    )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

My desired filtered array(filtered by current month), would be this:

```
[
   {
      "participant_id": 2,
      "name": "Bond James",
      "allschedules": [
         {
            "schedule_id": 10,
            "name": "CP - James Bond",
            "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts": 10,
            "start_date": "2022-04-11 07:00:00",
            "end_date": "2022-05-11 09:00:00",
            "shifts": [
               "2022-04-11 07:00:00",
               "2022-04-13 07:00:00",
               "2022-04-18 07:00:00",
               "2022-04-20 07:00:00",
               "2022-04-25 07:00:00",
               "2022-04-27 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-02 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-04 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-09 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-11 07:00:00"
            ]
         },
         {
            "schedule_id": 11,
            "name": "James_Miller_App_Test",
            "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
            "number_of_shifts": 30,
            "start_date": "2022-04-21 07:00:00",
            "end_date": "2022-05-20 15:00:00",
            "shifts": [
               "2022-04-30 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-01 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-02 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-03 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-04 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-05 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-06 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-07 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-08 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-09 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-10 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-11 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-12 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-13 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-14 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-15 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-16 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-17 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-18 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-19 07:00:00",
               "2022-05-20 07:00:00"
            ]
         },
      ]
   }
]
```

This is my expected result after filtering. Note that only the participant that has shifts in the current month is returned AND the `allschedules` object only has items that have atleast one date that is in the current month.

Comment: you also missed `return` on line with `find` statement.

Comment: *"where the dates inside the shifts array is for the current month."*: this is open for interpretation: do you want the participants for which **all** schedules have **at least one** date which is in the current month, or participants for which **at least one** schedule has **all of** its dates in the current month, or any other permutation of **any** versus **all**? Or do you want the *shifts* to be filtered for the current month, and if that results in at least one shift, then that schedule should remain, and if such schedules remain for a participant, that participant should be retained?

Comment: Hello @trincot. The objective is to have the array be filtered to return only participants that have a shift/shifts that is/are in the current month. Hope that makes sense

Comment: *"...participants that have a shift/shifts that is/are in the current month"*: For *all* their schedules, or for at least one of their schedules?

Comment: The allschedules object after filtering, will only contain the schedules for shifts in the current month.

Comment: So, **all** of a participant's schedules must have **at least** one shift that is in the current month. Can you confirm?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: So the result should be an empty array now (as we are in month 5). Can you confirm?

Comment: @suo I'm wondering if you need 1 schedule match or if all schedules match in the current month?

Comment: That is correct @trincot

Comment: So is the answer below correct?

Comment: Sorry @trincot, participant with id 2 has some shedules with shifts in the current month, to be more specific, schedules with ids: 10 and 11. So the result would be only that participant returned with allschedules array with 2 items that contain schedule_id 10 and 11.

Comment: @suo, you'll have to better define what you need. Above you confirmed to me that **all** of a participant's schedules must have **at least** one shift that is in the current month. Now you say something different. Please edit your question and make sure there is no ambiguity. The words **all** and **at least one** are important on all levels (shifts, schedules). Furthermore, you are now also saying that not only the participants should be filtered, but also the schedules they have. We can now also ask whether the shifts should be filtered as well so they only contain the current month's shifts

Comment: Please provide expected result, with certain conditions

Comment: Ok. I'll edit the question now to better capture desired result. Thanks guys.

Comment: I've edited the question to showcase desired end result.

Comment: Ok, that clarifies it. In summary: the result should include participants that have **at least** one schedule for which **at least** one shift is in the current month, and in that result only those schedules should be included that have a shift in the current month. No filtering should be happening on the shifts themselves which can still include other months. See my answer.

Comment: I modified my answer to align with your case too. You can check it out again @suo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you not only want to filter the `participants` array, but also want for each retained participant that its `allschedules` array is filtered too.

So, then you would better return a new object structure to avoid that the input structure is mutated.

Also, checking only the month part of a date may not give good results when the schedules span more than one year. It will be better to check that also the year matches:

Here is how it could be done:

```js
let participants = [{"participant_id": 2,"name": "Bond James","allschedules": [{"schedule_id": 1,"name": "James_Bond_SIL_January_22 (AM) - 07:00 - 15:00","schedule_type": "Individual Schedule","number_of_shifts": 31,"start_date": "2022-01-01 07:00:00","end_date": "2022-01-31 15:00:00","shifts": ["2022-01-01 07:00:00","2022-01-02 07:00:00","2022-01-03 07:00:00","2022-01-04 07:00:00"]},{"schedule_id": 2,"name": "Bonds-1:2 Schedule","schedule_type": "Individual Schedule","number_of_shifts": 5,"start_date": "2022-01-12 07:00:00","end_date": "2022-01-16 11:00:00","shifts": ["2022-01-12 07:00:00","2022-01-13 07:00:00","2022-01-14 07:00:00","2022-01-15 07:00:00","2022-01-16 07:00:00"]},{"schedule_id": 9,"name": "test april","schedule_type": "Individual Schedule","number_of_shifts": 4,"start_date": "2022-04-09 16:00:00","end_date": "2022-04-12 20:00:00","shifts": ["2022-04-09 16:00:00","2022-04-10 16:00:00","2022-04-11 16:00:00","2022-04-12 16:00:00"]},{"schedule_id": 10,"name": "CP - James Bond","schedule_type": "Individual Schedule","number_of_shifts": 10,"start_date": "2022-04-11 07:00:00","end_date": "2022-05-11 09:00:00","shifts": ["2022-04-11 07:00:00","2022-04-13 07:00:00","2022-04-18 07:00:00","2022-04-20 07:00:00","2022-04-25 07:00:00","2022-04-27 07:00:00","2022-05-02 07:00:00","2022-05-04 07:00:00","2022-05-09 07:00:00","2022-05-11 07:00:00"]},{"schedule_id": 11,"name": "James_Miller_App_Test","schedule_type": "Individual Schedule","number_of_shifts": 30,"start_date": "2022-04-21 07:00:00","end_date": "2022-05-20 15:00:00","shifts": ["2022-04-30 07:00:00","2022-05-01 07:00:00","2022-05-02 07:00:00","2022-05-03 07:00:00","2022-05-04 07:00:00","2022-05-05 07:00:00","2022-05-06 07:00:00","2022-05-07 07:00:00","2022-05-08 07:00:00","2022-05-09 07:00:00","2022-05-10 07:00:00","2022-05-11 07:00:00","2022-05-12 07:00:00","2022-05-13 07:00:00","2022-05-14 07:00:00","2022-05-15 07:00:00","2022-05-16 07:00:00","2022-05-17 07:00:00","2022-05-18 07:00:00","2022-05-19 07:00:00","2022-05-20 07:00:00"]},{"schedule_id": 12,"name": "Grouped Schedule for April 2022","schedule_type": "Shared/Grouped Schedule","number_of_shifts": 3,"start_date": "2022-04-28 12:00:00","end_date": "2022-04-30 18:00:00","shifts": ["2022-04-28 12:00:00","2022-04-29 12:00:00","2022-04-30 12:00:00"]}]},{"participant_id": 3,"name": "Barkley Charles","allschedules": [{"schedule_id": 12,"name": "Grouped Schedule for April 2022","schedule_type": "Shared/Grouped Schedule","number_of_shifts": 3,"start_date": "2022-04-28 12:00:00","end_date": "2022-04-30 18:00:00","shifts": ["2022-04-28 12:00:00","2022-04-29 12:00:00","2022-04-30 12:00:00"]}]}];

const currentMonth = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-SE").slice(0, 7); // YYYY-MM format
const result = participants.map(participant => ({
    ...participant,
    allschedules: participant.allschedules.filter(({shifts}) => 
        shifts.some(shift => shift.startsWith(currentMonth))
    )
})).filter(({allschedules: {length}}) => length);

console.log(result);
```

NB: I didn't use momentjs as even the authors [discourage its use](https://momentjs.com/docs/) in new projects. Moreover, it is very easy to make the month comparison with native JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

`shifts` actually are the data pieces of `start_date` and `end_date`, so you just need to check `start_date` month is within the current month or not instead of checking all `shifts`. If it is, we just need to add it to the result

Moment.js version

```
//const currentMonth = moment().format("M") //get the actual today 
const currentMonth = moment("2022-05-01 12:00:00").format("M")

const result = participants.map((participant) => ({
  ...participant,
  allschedules: participant.allschedules.filter(schedule => moment(schedule.start_date).format("M") === currentMonth || moment(schedule.end_date).format("M") === currentMonth)
})).filter((participant) => participant.allschedules && participant.allschedules.length)

console.log(result)
```

```js
let participants = [{
"participant_id": 2,
"name": "Bond James",
"allschedules": [{
    "schedule_id": 1,
    "name": "James_Bond_SIL_January_22 (AM) - 07:00 - 15:00",
    "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
    "number_of_shifts": 31,
    "start_date": "2022-01-01 07:00:00",
    "end_date": "2022-01-31 15:00:00",
    "shifts": [
      "2022-01-01 07:00:00",
      "2022-01-02 07:00:00",
      "2022-01-03 07:00:00",
      "2022-01-04 07:00:00"
    ]
  },
  {
    "schedule_id": 2,
    "name": "Bonds-1:2 Schedule",
    "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
    "number_of_shifts": 5,
    "start_date": "2022-01-12 07:00:00",
    "end_date": "2022-01-16 11:00:00",
    "shifts": [
      "2022-01-12 07:00:00",
      "2022-01-13 07:00:00",
      "2022-01-14 07:00:00",
      "2022-01-15 07:00:00",
      "2022-01-16 07:00:00"
    ]
  },
  {
    "schedule_id": 9,
    "name": "test april",
    "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
    "number_of_shifts": 4,
    "start_date": "2022-04-09 16:00:00",
    "end_date": "2022-04-12 20:00:00",
    "shifts": [
      "2022-04-09 16:00:00",
      "2022-04-10 16:00:00",
      "2022-04-11 16:00:00",
      "2022-04-12 16:00:00"
    ]
  },
  {
    "schedule_id": 10,
    "name": "CP - James Bond",
    "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
    "number_of_shifts": 10,
    "start_date": "2022-04-11 07:00:00",
    "end_date": "2022-05-11 09:00:00",
    "shifts": [
      "2022-04-11 07:00:00",
      "2022-04-13 07:00:00",
      "2022-04-18 07:00:00",
      "2022-04-20 07:00:00",
      "2022-04-25 07:00:00",
      "2022-04-27 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-02 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-04 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-09 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-11 07:00:00"
    ]
  },
  {
    "schedule_id": 11,
    "name": "James_Miller_App_Test",
    "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
    "number_of_shifts": 30,
    "start_date": "2022-04-21 07:00:00",
    "end_date": "2022-05-20 15:00:00",
    "shifts": [
      "2022-04-30 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-01 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-02 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-03 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-04 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-05 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-06 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-07 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-08 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-09 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-10 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-11 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-12 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-13 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-14 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-15 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-16 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-17 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-18 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-19 07:00:00",
      "2022-05-20 07:00:00"
    ]
  },
  {
    "schedule_id": 12,
    "name": "Grouped Schedule for April 2022",
    "schedule_type": "Shared/Grouped Schedule",
    "number_of_shifts": 3,
    "start_date": "2022-04-28 12:00:00",
    "end_date": "2022-04-30 18:00:00",
    "shifts": [
      "2022-04-28 12:00:00",
      "2022-04-29 12:00:00",
      "2022-04-30 12:00:00"
    ]
  }
]
  },
  {
"participant_id": 3,
"name": "Barkley Charles",
"allschedules": [{
  "schedule_id": 12,
  "name": "Grouped Schedule for April 2022",
  "schedule_type": "Shared/Grouped Schedule",
  "number_of_shifts": 3,
  "start_date": "2022-04-28 12:00:00",
  "end_date": "2022-04-30 18:00:00",
  "shifts": [
    "2022-04-28 12:00:00",
    "2022-04-29 12:00:00",
    "2022-04-30 12:00:00"
  ]
}]
  }
]

//simulate today is 1st May 2022
//const currentMonth = moment().format("M") //get the actual today 
const currentMonth = moment("2022-05-01 12:00:00").format("M")

const result = participants.map((participant) => ({
  ...participant,
  allschedules: participant.allschedules.filter(schedule => moment(schedule.start_date).format("M") === currentMonth || moment(schedule.end_date).format("M") === currentMonth)
})).filter((participant) => participant.allschedules && participant.allschedules.length)

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript version (it's more preferable because it's lighter than `moment` that would save user traffic to load your scripts)

```
//simulate today is May 1st 2022
//const currentMonth = new Date().format("M") //get the actual today 
const currentMonth = new Date("2022-05-01 12:00:00").getMonth()

const result = participants.map((participant) => ({
  ...participant,
  allschedules: participant.allschedules.filter(schedule => new Date(schedule.start_date).getMonth() === currentMonth || new Date(schedule.end_date).getMonth() === currentMonth)
})).filter((participant) => participant.allschedules && participant.allschedules.length)

console.log(result)
```

```js
let participants = [{
    "participant_id": 2,
    "name": "Bond James",
    "allschedules": [{
        "schedule_id": 1,
        "name": "James_Bond_SIL_January_22 (AM) - 07:00 - 15:00",
        "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
        "number_of_shifts": 31,
        "start_date": "2022-01-01 07:00:00",
        "end_date": "2022-01-31 15:00:00",
        "shifts": [
          "2022-01-01 07:00:00",
          "2022-01-02 07:00:00",
          "2022-01-03 07:00:00",
          "2022-01-04 07:00:00"
        ]
      },
      {
        "schedule_id": 2,
        "name": "Bonds-1:2 Schedule",
        "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
        "number_of_shifts": 5,
        "start_date": "2022-01-12 07:00:00",
        "end_date": "2022-01-16 11:00:00",
        "shifts": [
          "2022-01-12 07:00:00",
          "2022-01-13 07:00:00",
          "2022-01-14 07:00:00",
          "2022-01-15 07:00:00",
          "2022-01-16 07:00:00"
        ]
      },
      {
        "schedule_id": 9,
        "name": "test april",
        "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
        "number_of_shifts": 4,
        "start_date": "2022-04-09 16:00:00",
        "end_date": "2022-04-12 20:00:00",
        "shifts": [
          "2022-04-09 16:00:00",
          "2022-04-10 16:00:00",
          "2022-04-11 16:00:00",
          "2022-04-12 16:00:00"
        ]
      },
      {
        "schedule_id": 10,
        "name": "CP - James Bond",
        "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
        "number_of_shifts": 10,
        "start_date": "2022-04-11 07:00:00",
        "end_date": "2022-05-11 09:00:00",
        "shifts": [
          "2022-04-11 07:00:00",
          "2022-04-13 07:00:00",
          "2022-04-18 07:00:00",
          "2022-04-20 07:00:00",
          "2022-04-25 07:00:00",
          "2022-04-27 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-02 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-04 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-09 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-11 07:00:00"
        ]
      },
      {
        "schedule_id": 11,
        "name": "James_Miller_App_Test",
        "schedule_type": "Individual Schedule",
        "number_of_shifts": 30,
        "start_date": "2022-04-21 07:00:00",
        "end_date": "2022-05-20 15:00:00",
        "shifts": [
          "2022-04-30 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-01 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-02 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-03 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-04 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-05 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-06 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-07 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-08 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-09 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-10 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-11 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-12 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-13 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-14 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-15 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-16 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-17 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-18 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-19 07:00:00",
          "2022-05-20 07:00:00"
        ]
      },
      {
        "schedule_id": 12,
        "name": "Grouped Schedule for April 2022",
        "schedule_type": "Shared/Grouped Schedule",
        "number_of_shifts": 3,
        "start_date": "2022-04-28 12:00:00",
        "end_date": "2022-04-30 18:00:00",
        "shifts": [
          "2022-04-28 12:00:00",
          "2022-04-29 12:00:00",
          "2022-04-30 12:00:00"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "participant_id": 3,
    "name": "Barkley Charles",
    "allschedules": [{
      "schedule_id": 12,
      "name": "Grouped Schedule for April 2022",
      "schedule_type": "Shared/Grouped Schedule",
      "number_of_shifts": 3,
      "start_date": "2022-04-28 12:00:00",
      "end_date": "2022-04-30 18:00:00",
      "shifts": [
        "2022-04-28 12:00:00",
        "2022-04-29 12:00:00",
        "2022-04-30 12:00:00"
      ]
    }]
  }
]

//simulate today is May 1st 2022
//const currentMonth = new Date().format("M") //get the actual today 
const currentMonth = new Date("2022-05-01 12:00:00").getMonth()

const result = participants.map((participant) => ({
  ...participant,
  allschedules: participant.allschedules.filter(schedule => new Date(schedule.start_date).getMonth() === currentMonth || new Date(schedule.end_date).getMonth() === currentMonth)
})).filter((participant) => participant.allschedules && participant.allschedules.length)

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```